# How to use Hibernate as persistence provider in TomEE

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, apache-tomee, openejb

I am facing an issue in using Hibernate 3.x with TomEE.

Previously we were using Hibernate with tomcat 1.6  and when we changed the container to TomEE, Hibernate fails.

TomEE by default uses OpenEJB's JPA as the persistence provider.

Tried searching in google but nothing helps.

http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-hibernate.html

Can anyone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate supports [JPA as follows](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/):

- JPA 1.0: Hibernate ORM 3.2 or later
- JPA 2.0: Hibernate ORM 3.5 or later
- JPA 2.1: Hibernate ORM 4.3 or later
- JPA 2.2: Hibernate ORM 5.3 or later
- JPA 3.0: Hibernate ORM 5.5 or later

So make sure you use the proper JPA version against your current Hibernate 3.x version.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved this issue by removing the "\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1\conf\conf.d" folder and it worked for me.